# XML Parsing - Null Object Reference - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception

I am parsing XML datas, but when in XML is tag without text (only `<item/>` ) it writes error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'java.lang.String org.w3c.dom.Node.getNodeValue()' on a null object
>   reference

This is function where I get error:

```
private static String getNode(String sTag, Element eElement) {
    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0)
            .getChildNodes();
    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
    return nValue.getNodeValue(); //here I get error
}
```

Can somebody help me with this problem?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Check on `null` if it is not null `return` value if it is `null` return something else for example an empty `String`

Comment: Just because `nlList.item(0)` existed, doesn't mean it's not null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem occurs because that `nValue` is `null`.
You need to decide how your method should act in this situation and use this code

```
if(nValue!=null)
{
    return nValue.getNodeValue();
}
else
{
    //the tag has no value
    //return other default value or maybe throw your own exception 
}
```

Comment: It's my pleasure!